# Looking for pattern for unobstrusive jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a jquery plugin and I'd like to allow a programmatic creation and unobstrusive creation (for instance: automatically create plugin for elements with a specific css class´)

I have some ideas how to implement this but I wonder if there is any "good practice" or pattern available to check. I'd like to follow a recommended approach if any in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-write-jquery-plugins:4f72ab2e-7310-4a74-817a-0a04cbdd56cb) is a nice write-up...

also consider examining [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: IMHO the write up is barely relevant.  It doesn't demonstrate how a plugin would automatically bind itself to all current _and future_ instances of a particular class, per the OP's question.

Comment: @Alnitak IMHO the op makes absolutely no mention of _future_ instances of anything, just unobtrusive plugin initialization...

Comment: wow... and a downvote?.. why being such a jerk? read the question dude, its not complicated

Comment: maybe my comments focussed too much on the dynamic element question, but the fact is that the linked article (and the reference to jquerymobile) don't give any help to the OP's question of _unobtrusive_ (i.e. automatic) addition of a plugin to a set of elements.

Comment: lawlz... really?.. even the part titled "How to write self-initializing plugins" that mentions some advantages and disadvantages to the approach. or the fact that jquerymobile does exactly what he asked about doing to initialize every one of its widgets? furthermore, i still see no mention of the _dynamic element question_ you made up out of thin air. you sir, are an imbecile.

Comment: ironically, it was that very article that steered me towards the problem of dynamic elements, which I already admitted I over emphasised.  I still think that article is poorly written because the code in the section about "self-initialisation" looks like standalone code, and only in the conclusion (which I had skipped) does he show a "complete" example somewhat like the one in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is not to do it.

There's no practical way to automatically detect the creation of elements with a particular class, so the *normal* pattern is to use a selector to find those elements *after they've been created* and then specifically bind the plugin to those elements.

Within a plugin's source file you *could* do this:

```
(function($) {

     // plugin code here
     $.fn.foo = ...

     // tell jQuery to bind the plugin to existing
     //  .foo elements once the DOM is ready
     $(function() {
         $('.foo').foo();
     });
 })(jQuery);
```

although IMHO it's generally bad manners for a plugin to add itself to an element without deliberate programmer intervention.

You'll also need to arrange to call `$('.foo').foo()` later anytime you dynamically create any new such elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By automatically I meant: created by the plugin without any js code added by library client

Comment: of course you can, jquerymobile is based on the very idea, by recognized data-role on a tag and using other data-??? attributes to describe state, etc.

Comment: ... sry not dynamically created elements, but I did not garner that was a requirement from the op's question...

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool plugins have to be invoked.  You can do that in the plugin's own .js file by having the plugin register its own `document.ready` handler.  But that still won't work on dynamically created elements.

Comment: @Alnitak: I know that plugin has to be invoked. Just wanted to delegate the responsability of invoking it to the js library itself detecting a css class or data attribute. I know how to do it, but wanted to check for good practices and well developed plugins

Comment: @TimmyO'Tool here is a nice write-up http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-write-jquery-plugins:4f72ab2e-7310-4a74-817a-0a04cbdd56cb

Comment: @happytime harry: thanks! If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: note that the method shown therein really just degenerates to what I said above - the author has just triggered the step of "finding the elements after they've been created" in the callback of an AJAX request.  The plugin itself hasn't done it.